# Data security implications of using Android over iOS

Tags: appsec, android, ios

What are the security implications of using Android as opposed to iOS? Many sources say Android is much less secure and much less capable of handing a user's data in a secure manner. What are the main failings or disadvantages of using Android?

I.e., Apple using sandboxing and has a secure runtime environment which Android apparently does not.

Comment: can you please cite the sources which claim so.

Comment: As already explained in the answer, "*Apple using sandboxing and has a secure runtime environment which Android apparently does not.*" is not correct, unless you mean different sandboxing.

Answer (score 2):

> like all security features, the Application Sandbox is not
>   unbreakable. However, to break out of the Application Sandbox in a
>   properly configured device, one must compromise the security of the
>   the **Linux kernel**.

Android much less secure? Not so sure about that(**subjective**).
**1- Security implications?**

*Misc:*

- Open-source.
- Android IPC (Intents, Services and BroadcastReceivers).

*Linux Security:*

- ASLR, NX, SELinux.
- System Partition and Safe Mode.
- ***Application Sandbox.***
- Process isolation.
- Filesystem Permissions.

*User Security Features:*

- Filesystem Encryption(not enabled by default)
- Password Protection.
- Device Administration.
- Keychain.
- App permissions.

**2- Disadvantages?**

- Rooting of devices: It's great for attackers or geeks, but it's a security nightmare. Root access, exploits, file system exposed with shared_prefs, sqlite_db, ...
- SSL mutual authentication in the Webview: Impossible untill recently, thanks to hidden/unofficial [APIs](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53491).
- Handling of private/company PKI CAs: Keychain added in api level 14.
- [Android Runtime Code Injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30560/android-runtime-code-injection)
- Android database(SQLite): No encryption! ==> SQLcipher for sensitive data.

[kernel-security](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/overview/kernel-security.html)

Answer (score 1):

Android does have app sandboxing, which is in some aspects stronger, and in other aspects weaker, than iOS. But if your question refers to end-user's choice to keep their personal data private, then the choice of applications is much more important than the decision whether to use an Android or iOS - powered device. Also, both systems keep user data in the cloud, and the security of either Google Cloud storage or Apple Cloud storage is a greater risk factor than the "sandboxing" on the device.